# ListView not refreshing its views even after calling notify data set changes

Tags: android, listview, view, refresh

Good day.I search the whole internet.Tried every bit of code this or that way.But nothing helped me at all!I have simple list view with simple custom adapter with simple custom view.Im adding some information onto in in for() loop.Two different places i call that damned adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in loop and when the loop is over.But that freaking list view won't update its view.I call invalidate,invalidate views,i call 10 times notify but still that idiotic list view won't update its views.
Putting the code of whole class thats going on.
First is the adapter

```
public class FindPaqNearMeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    static int myint = 0;
    Context context;
    public static int mypositon = 0;
    View myview = null;
    protected List<FindPaqNearMeSimpleClass> followsSimpleClasses;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public OnGetPositionForView getPositionForView;
    public FindPaqNearMeAdapter(Context context, List<FindPaqNearMeSimpleClass> listCars) {
        this.followsSimpleClasses = listCars;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return followsSimpleClasses.size();
    }

    public FindPaqNearMeSimpleClass getItem(int position) {
        return followsSimpleClasses.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.findpaqnearmesingleitem,
                    parent, false);
            holder.userimage = (de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.userimage);
            holder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.startdate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.startdate);
            holder.enddate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.enddate);
            holder.price = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            holder.to = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.to);
            holder.type = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.paqtype);
            holder.from = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.from);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            FindPaqNearMeSimpleClass feedback = followsSimpleClasses.get(position);
            holder.name.setText(feedback.getName());
            holder.startdate.setText(feedback.getStartdatre());
            holder.enddate.setText(feedback.getEnddate());
            holder.price.setText(feedback.getPrice());
            holder.to.setText(feedback.getTo());
            holder.type.setText(feedback.getType());
            holder.from.setText(feedback.getFrom());
            holder.userimage.setImageBitmap(feedback.getFollowersiamge());
        }
        return convertView;
    }
    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        TextView startdate;
        TextView enddate;
        TextView price;
        TextView from;
        TextView to;
        TextView type;
        de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView userimage;
    }


}
```

second is the holder of this adapter;

```
/**
 * Created by vladimir on 07.08.15.
 */
public class FindPaqNearMeSimpleClass {
    private Bitmap userimage;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String startdatre;
    private String from;
    private String to;
    private String enddate;
    private String price;
    private String longitude;
    private String latitude;
    private String paqid;
    private String userid;

    public String getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(String userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public String getPaqid() {
        return paqid;
    }

    public void setPaqid(String paqid) {
        this.paqid = paqid;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getStartdatre() {
        return startdatre;
    }

    public void setStartdatre(String startdatre) {
        this.startdatre = startdatre;
    }

    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    public String getEnddate() {
        return enddate;
    }

    public void setEnddate(String enddate) {
        this.enddate = enddate;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public FindPaqNearMeSimpleClass(Bitmap userimage, String name, String type, String startdatre, String from, String to, String enddate, String price) {
        this.userimage = userimage;
        this.name = name;
        this.paqid = paqid;
        this.type = type;
        this.startdatre = startdatre;
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.userid=userid;
        this.enddate = enddate;
        this.price = price;
        this.longitude=longitude;
        this.latitude=latitude;
    }

    public void setFollowersiamge(Bitmap followersiamge) {
        this.userimage = followersiamge;
    }

    public Bitmap getFollowersiamge () {
        return userimage;
    }

}
```

Last is my main class,inside which there is asynctask,and on which onPostExecute() i call method `addpaqs(result)` which doing all this things here is the code;

```
 public class RequestPaqs extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(ServerUrlConstants.getAllPaqs);

            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(

                    HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

            try {
                reqEntity.addPart("type", new StringBody("2"));
                reqEntity.addPart("lat",new StringBody(readLatitude()));
                reqEntity.addPart("lng", new StringBody(readLongitude()));

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                post.setEntity(reqEntity);
                // post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
            } finally {

            }


            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = null;
            try {
                response = client.execute(post);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                paqsresponse = responseBody;
                Log.d("anasun", responseBody);


            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            return paqsresponse;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if(result.length()<7){
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"latitude.txt");
                File file2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"longitue.txt");
                DeleteRecursive(file);
                DeleteRecursive(file2);
                return;
            }else{
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"latitude.txt");
                File file2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"longitue.txt");
                DeleteRecursive(file);
                DeleteRecursive(file2);
                try {
                    addpaqs(result);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            super.onPostExecute(result);

        }
    }
```

And here is my addpaqs method

```
private void addpaqs(String result) throws JSONException {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i =0;i<array.length();i++){
            JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
            creator_first_name = object.optString("creator_first_name");
            creator_last_name = object.optString("creator_last_name");
            paqtype = object.optString("paq_type");
            from_country = object.optString("from_country");
            from_city = object.optString("from_city");
            from_street = object.optString("from_street");
            from_state = object.optString("from_state");
            to_city = object.optString("to_city");
            to_country = object.optString("to_country");
            to_street = object.optString("to_street");
            to_state = object.optString("to_state");
            startdate = object.optString("start_date");
            enddate = object.optString("end_date");
            price = object.optString("price");
            creator_first_name = object.optString("creator_first_name");
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.com_facebook_profile_picture_blank_square);
            findPaqNearMeSimpleClass = new FindPaqNearMeSimpleClass(bitmap,creator_first_name+" "+creator_last_name,paqtype,startdate,from_country+"/"+from_city+"/"+from_state+"/"+from_street,to_country+"/"+to_city+"/"+to_state+"/"+to_street,enddate,price);
            findPaqNearMeSimpleClassArrayList.add(findPaqNearMeSimpleClass);
            listview.invalidate();
            listview.invalidateViews();
            findPaqNearMeAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            findPaqNearMeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.d("safhkjasfas","logger");
        }
        loadingbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      findPaqNearMeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Antyhing I'm doing wrong????
EDIT: and here is the code how i do init all these classes;

```
listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        findPaqNearMeSimpleClassArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        findPaqNearMeAdapter = new FindPaqNearMeAdapter(this,findPaqNearMeSimpleClassArrayList);
        listview.setAdapter(findPaqNearMeAdapter);
```

Comment: Where is the code where you attach findPaqNearMeSimpleClassArrayList to findPaqNearMeAdapter?

Comment: here the way i init all that

Comment: findPaqNearMeSimpleClassArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        findPaqNearMeAdapter = new FindPaqNearMeAdapter(this,findPaqNearMeSimpleClassArrayList);
        listview.setAdapter(findPaqNearMeAdapter);

Comment: i edited answer you can check :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change getView() method in adapter

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.findpaqnearmesingleitem,
                parent, false);
        holder.userimage = (de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.userimage);
        holder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.startdate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.startdate);
        holder.enddate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.enddate);
        holder.price = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        holder.to = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.to);
        holder.type = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.paqtype);
        holder.from = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.from);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    FindPaqNearMeSimpleClass feedback = followsSimpleClasses.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(feedback.getName());
    holder.startdate.setText(feedback.getStartdatre());
    holder.enddate.setText(feedback.getEnddate());
    holder.price.setText(feedback.getPrice());
    holder.to.setText(feedback.getTo());
    holder.type.setText(feedback.getType());
    holder.from.setText(feedback.getFrom());
    holder.userimage.setImageBitmap(feedback.getFollowersiamge());

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but i did not understand what exactly i should change and should be changed?

Comment: wait a minute...i did put your code and hmm wow it worked....what you have changed bro???please tell

Comment: i don't know what you have changed but it worked,this is GOLD,thank you very much and  ill dig into this to see what you have changed!

Comment: @aasssaasasaasa getView() method in your adapter code is running when convertView is null, view inflating but data is not set. because [else]

Comment: ohhhhh true got it now tyvm